# mysql insert and check not on blacklist table

Tags: php, mysql, blacklist

Hi i want to make an insert in my mysql database but first I want to check if the email is not avaible in the table blacklist. If the mail is in the blacklist I want to ignore the insert.

```
$sqlinsertqueue = "
INSERT INTO queue Set
email = '$email'"
mysql_query($sqlinsertqueue,$db);
```

My blacklist has also the field email. My tablename from my blacklist is blacklist.

Comment: So ... check whether the e-mail is on the blacklist.

Comment: Ok but how can I make it in the mysql string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);

//check blacklist
$sql = "
SELECT
        COUNT(*)
FROM
        blacklist
WHERE
        email='$email'
";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result,  MYSQL_NUM);

if ($row[0] == 0)
{
    //insert
    $sqlinsertqueue = "
INSERT INTO queue Set
email = '$email'";
    mysql_query($sqlinsertqueue,$db);    
}
```

Don't use mysql_* functions - they are deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Since @EdGibbs deleted his answer before I got to say this, he was on the right track with an `INSERT ... SELECT`;

```
INSERT INTO queue (email) 
  SELECT 'dummy@example.com' FROM DUAL
  WHERE 'dummy@example.com' NOT IN (SELECT email from Blacklist);
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea8a8/1).

You may want to use `PDO` or `MySQLi` instead of the deprecated `mysql_*` api, or at the *very least* do [`mysql_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php) on the email addresses before inserting them into the SQL query.

Comment: +1 @JoachimIsaksson - I didn't realize MySQL supported `DUAL`. I tend to think in Oracle and translate `FROM DUAL` to "don't use a FROM clause" when doing MySL, so I tried `INSERT ... SELECT 'email' WHERE NOT IN ...` and deleted my answer when that didn't work. I could've at least *tried* `DUAL` to make sure :)